# Read csv with use of placeholder

Tags: r, csv

I have a folder containing 5 `.csv` files that differ regarding their ending: `...foot.csv`, `...arm.csv`, and so on. I would like to read them using `read.csv` without having to specify the full file name, that is, by only giving the ending. I do not know how to best do this similarly to MATLAB, where one can put "*foot.txt".

```
 path <- "E:/10 Data/FootHand/07 Temperature/"
 folder <- "10-12 12 14_HL"

 wd <- paste(path, folder, sep="")
 setwd(wd)


Ankle.r <- read.csv("*foot.csv", header = T, sep = "", dec = ".")
 # I know the * does not work in R, but should illustrate what I mean :).
```

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `list.files()` to get a list of files and loop over them and use `rbind` to add the lines to your `data.frame`. But make sure the header is always the same, otherwise this might crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the right name of the file with:

```
name<-list.files("C:/path/to/file/")[grep("foot",list.files(path = "c:/path/to/file/"),ignore.case = T)]
```

And then load with:

```
Ankle.r<-read.csv(file=paste("C:/path/to/file",name,sep=""),header=T,sep=",")
```

With this approach you don't even need to bother to know the exact ending of the file name, as `grep` will get you the name with any match (in this case, "foot"). Be careful, though, of not defining a substring that will match more than one file!

Answer (score 0):

So maybe a solution would look like this.

```
csv_files <- list.files('.*foot.csv')

Ankle.r <- data.frame()
for( csv_file in cdv_files) {
    Ankle.r <- rbind(Ankle.r, read.csv(cdv_file))
}
```

This will crash, if the header is not always the same. In this case you have to do a little bit more, like adding NAs or so.